# Keras Softmax is Hardmaxing for some reason

Tags: keras, softmax

I am new to Keras and am bit confused at the moment:

```
def get_compiled_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1000, input_shape = (1000,), activation='relu', kernel_initializer = 'glorot_uniform'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1000, activation='relu', kernel_initializer = 'glorot_uniform'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(41, activation='softmax', kernel_initializer = 'glorot_uniform')
])

    model.compile(optimizer='SGD', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

I then call my model as follows:

```
model = get_compiled_model()
for i in range(10):
     model.fit(train_object, epochs=10)
     test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_object, verbose=2)
```

I keep getting 0 accuracy even after a lot of training. I think it is because the model is hardmaxing from the start:

```
for row in test_object.take(1):
    row
print(model.predict(row[0])[0])
```

array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)

This behavior happens even at the beginning which is confusing since we would expect something with decimals rather than all 0's and 1's.

Any help would be appreciated. To rephrase the question I am confused to why the model is hardmaxing instead of softmazing.

Comment: You give very little information. Model construction looks fine. Do you have also 0 accuracy in training? Have you normalized both training and test data in same manner, for example between 0 and 1?

Comment: What's your data? Looks like vanishing gradient.